# EF 6.4 DbCommandInterceptor correlation C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to alter parameters in the DbCommandInterceptor to be able to convert a datetime to UTC before saving. In some cases I don't want to convert the parameter based on the entities property.

example:

```
public class UtcReadInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        foreach (DbParameter p in command.Parameters)
        {
            if (p.DbType != DbType.DateTime2 || ShouldSkip(p)) { continue; }

            var date = p.Value as DateTime?;

            if (!date.HasValue) { continue; }

            p.Value = date.Value.ToUniversalTime()
        }

        base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
    }
} 

private bool ShouldSkip(DbParameter p)
{
   // Look up the parameter in EF metadata and choose ignore or let through.
}
```

What I'm looking for is some way to know if a given field shouldn't be converted to UTC. I need to somehow either look up which field it is (and on which entity) in the context or somehow how mark it in some sort of lookup to be able to know to skip it or not.

Does anyone know how to correlate the parameter to the field on the EF entity or alter the parameter somehow from EF to know if can skip it when converting datetime parameters to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find an answer this and after reading the EF6 code there looks like there is very little to pass to parameters that are based on the entities field. The code appears to just have defaults for given field types and uses those.

The only way I could separate the column types was by setting one type to be DateTimeOffset and the other as just DateTime. Which come through as the parameters db types DateTime and DateTime2